# dojox matrix calender with default month functionality

Tags: dojo

I am using dojox matrix calender. I want only month matrix view. I am using

**calender.js**

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/ready", "dojox/calendar/Calendar", "dojo/store/Observable", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojox/calendar/MatrixView",
     "dojox/calendar/Keyboard", "dojox/calendar/Mouse","dojox/calendar/CalendarBase" ],
      function(parser, ready, Calendar, Observable, Memory, MatrixView, Keyboard, Mouse){
        ready(function(){
            var someData = [
                            {
                              id: 0,
                              summary: "Event 1",
                              startTime:  new Date(2012,0, 1, 10),
                              endTime: new Date(2012,0, 1, 12),
                              calendar: "Calendar1"
                            }

                          ];


          calendar = new calender({
                        date: new Date(2012, 0, 1),
                        dateInterval: "day",
                        store: new Observable(new Memory({data: someData})),
                        style: "position:relative;width:100%;height:250px;"},
                        "instructorDetailsMatrixCalender");

                  });

        }
      );
```

**calender.jsp**

```
<div id="instructorDetailsMatrixCalender" ></div>
```

When I click on navigation button (month, week) than popup close.

I want first time only month matrix view and in navigation title only (`< >`) button.

[Refer link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/calendar.html#matrix-view)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the full Calendar widget, just instantiate a dojox.calendar.MatrixView (the calendar views are widgets).

Simple Example:

```
require(
    ['dojo/ready', 'dojox/calendar/MatrixView', 'dojo/store/Observable', 'dojo/store/Memory'],
    function(ready, MatrixView, Observable, Memory){
        ready( function() {

            var monthlyMatrix;

            // instantiate calendar
            monthlyMatrix = new MatrixView(
                {
                    style: "position:relitive; height:400px"
                },
                'MatrixContainer'
            );
        });
    }
);
```

**References**

Dojo Forums: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/dojox-calendar-Calendar-month-only-view-td3997010.html;cid=1399571350937-308

Possible Stackoverflow Duplicate: [Adjusting functionality of Dojox Calendar Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983468/adjusting-functionality-of-dojox-calendar-widget)